# MongoDB: Querying multiple fields and indexing

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, indexing, mongodb-query

I am using MongoDB via mongoose.

1. What happens when you query an indexed field with a non-indexed field? See code below.

   ```
   // For example
   MyModel.find({ _id: '123', name: 'Jina'});
   ```

   Does MongoDB do a collection scan or does the index help in making the query efficient? And is the query any different from just using the `_id` field?
2. If MongoDB does a collection scan when you query a non-indexed field. Does querying multiple non-indexed fields speed up the query speed if a collection scan will be done all the same? Lets say if I query five non-indexed fields as opposed to two(both returning the same document(s)). Did both queries do the same collection scan?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand what is happening under the hood in mongo queries, you can use `explain`. For example, consider the following query:
`db.getCollection('users').find({"name":"ana"})`
which queries a non-indexed field. You can use explain on this query as below:

`db.getCollection('users').find({"name":"ana"}).explain("executionStats")`

Part of the result is:

```
"queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "anonymous-chat.users",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "name" : {
                "$eq" : "ana"
            }
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
            "filter" : {
                "name" : {
                    "$eq" : "ana"
                }
            },
            "direction" : "forward"
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : []
    },
```

As you can see, here we had a `COLLSCAN` which is a collection scan.
Now we just query _id and see the result:

```
db.getCollection('users').find({"_id":ObjectId("5ee9b6c125b9a9a426d9965f")}).explain("executionStats")
```

Here is the result:

```
"queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "anonymous-chat.users",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "_id" : {
                "$eq" : ObjectId("5ee9b6c125b9a9a426d9965f")
            }
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "IDHACK"
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : []
    },
```

As we can see, we have `IDHACK` when querying just _id.

Now we combine _id and name:

```
db.getCollection('users').find({"_id":ObjectId("5ee9b6c125b9a9a426d9965f"), "name":"ana"}).explain("executionStats")
```

This is the result:

```
 "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "anonymous-chat.users",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "$and" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : {
                        "$eq" : ObjectId("5ee9b6c125b9a9a426d9965f")
                    }
                }, 
                {
                    "name" : {
                        "$eq" : "ana"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "filter" : {
                "name" : {
                    "$eq" : "ana"
                }
            },
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "_id" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "_id_",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "_id" : []
                },
                "isUnique" : true,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 2,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "_id" : [ 
                        "[ObjectId('5ee9b6c125b9a9a426d9965f'), ObjectId('5ee9b6c125b9a9a426d9965f')]"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : []
    },
```

As we can see, The index helped with the query performance as we have two stages, an `IXSCAN` (Index Scan) and a `FETCH` stage which filters the documents of the last stage.

Now let's query multiple non-indexed fields to find out about your second question:

`db.getCollection('users').find({"name":"ana", "appId":1}).explain("executionStats")`

```
"queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "anonymous-chat.users",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "$and" : [ 
                {
                    "appId" : {
                        "$eq" : 1.0
                    }
                }, 
                {
                    "name" : {
                        "$eq" : "ana"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
            "filter" : {
                "$and" : [ 
                    {
                        "appId" : {
                            "$eq" : 1.0
                        }
                    }, 
                    {
                        "name" : {
                            "$eq" : "ana"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "direction" : "forward"
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : []
    },
```

There is only one collection scan for multiple fields as we can see above.